# Is PATH a special variable in zsh?

Tags: shell, zsh, environment-variables, path, pkg-config

The first two lines of my `.zprofile` are:

```
export PATH=<value>

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=<value>
```

The value of `PATH` is set correctly, but the value of second variable is empty. Is PATH a special variable in zsh which is inherited by interactive shells?

Solution: It was an error on my side. A had to login again for the zprofile to get sourced.

Comment: What do you consider "correctly"?

Comment: Does that file, or `~/.zshrc`, set it further?

Comment: +Kusalananda no it doesn't

Comment: +Michael Homer by correctly I mean it containes the value I assigned it to in `.zprofile`

Comment: By the last two comments, you contradicted yourself.

Comment: The question currently contains two assignments, both empty. You say that `PATH` is set correctly but the other one is empty. They were both assigned the same (empty) thing. What causes the "but" there? What is the "correct" thing that `PATH` is set to? How does it contrast with `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`?

Comment: Oops. Sorry for the confusion. I skipped the values cos I'm posting from my phone. I've set them both to the required values in `.zprofile`

Comment: Show us the actual content of the file. Is zsh actually your login shell? How do you log in (if you log in in graphical mode, `.zprofile` is probably not read)?

Comment: Ps. I know this was a careless post, so can I get a few more downvotes? For the `peer-pressure` badge :-)

Answer (score 3):

You assigned nothing to PKG_CONFIG_PATH in `.zprofile`, so it should be empty.  If PATH is also not empty after sourcing `.zprofile`, then PATH is being set somewhere else, possibly in `~zshrc`.

Note that the syntax for setting PATH in `zsh` can include something like `path+=('/apple/orange')` to append and `path=('/apple/orange' $path)` (or `path[1,0]=/apple/orange`) to prepend.

However, somewhere you should find another `export PATH` if you want PATH to be exported to subprocesses.